# Copy only files from a list into a new directory from a large directory structure

Tags: bash, files

I have a huge collection of flower pictures since I'm preparing a book. I'll use only some of them contained in a file called choosen.txt (actually a csv). I have to pick up the chosen ones from a folder tree organized in this way:

```
Pictures
├── Flowers 2020
│   ├── 1.- Spring 2020
│   ├── 2.- Summer 2020
│   ├── 3.- Autumn 2020
│   └── 4.- Winter 2020
└── Flowers 2021
    ├── 1.- Spring 2021
    ├── 2.- Summer 2021
    ├── 3.- Autumn 2021
    └── 4.- Winter 2021

10 directories, 5260 files
```

and copy every single chosen flower picture to a new folder called Chosen-ones (for example).
Hope I've explained right what I need to be done.

Below are some lines of the csv file `chosen.txt`

```
DSC10233.jpg
DSC10276.jpg
DSC10288.jpg
DSC10399.jpg
DSC10448.jpg
DSC10489.jpg
DSC10492.jpg
```

Is it possible using Bash or maybe a Python script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Vidal seems above comments are answered by you only last thing is will the file names in the `chosen.txt` are unique?

Comment: Sure it's possible...but teaching you how to script it might take longer than simply doing the job later in your workflow. For example, you will likely need to review each image manually anyway during each page's layout, and that might be a better time to copy the photos into a separate file (or directly into the manuscript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways to this on the command-line.

Assuming that you have only a list of file names (without the path), you can use a `while` loop to read your "chosen.txt" file, `find` to find the files in your source folder, and another `while` loop to copy them.

Defining variables lets you re-use the long command without having to edit it.

```bsh
list="/path/to/chosen.txt"
source="/path/to/Pictures"
dest="/path/to/destination"
```

```bsh
cat "chosen.txt" \
| while read n; do 
      find "$source" -name "$n" \
      | while read f; do
            cp "$f" "$dest/"
        done
  done
```

Or on a single line:

```bsh
cat "chosen.txt" | while read n; do find "$source" -name "$n" | while read f; do cp "$f" "$dest/"; done; done
```

An alternative, if your original .csv file also contains the path to the files, would be to build a list from that. Then you could use `rsync` with the `--files-from=` option to copy them by maintaining the original directory structure of the source.

Comment: Ooh I like the `rsync` idea. Your script works fine for me.

Comment: I also liked the rsync idea, but unfortunately in this case the list didn't include the path of the desired files.

Comment: @Vidal : if the list doesn't include the path, the output of the find command does. So that could be used to make a new list, or be piped directly into rsync.

Comment: Thanks. I have already marked the question as resolved with the while loop. Nevertheless will try it also with rsync since I like that command a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can do this with a very small Bash script.

I'm assuming that you have the list `chosen.txt` in your home directory, of which Pictures is a subdirectory. If this isn't the case, please adjust the paths accordingly.

First make the directory to move the files into. I'm assuming you've just opened a terminal and you're in your home directory. You can move the directory later.

```
mkdir ChosenOnes
```

Now check if you can find the correct files using your list like this:

```bsh
while read -r line; do find Pictures -name "$line" -ls; done < chosen.txt
```

If the result looks correct, you can copy the files by adjusting the command:

```bsh
while read -r line; do find Pictures -name "$line" -exec cp -vt ChosenOnes {} \; ; done < chosen.txt
```

We can make that look a bit better:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# read our list and
while read -r line; do
  # find the files in it and copy them to the new directory
  find Pictures -name "$line" -exec cp -vt ChosenOnes {} \;
done < chosen.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `while read -r line; do things; done < input-file` A `while` loop keeps on doing something as long as a condition holds. Here we are asking our list to be read line by line. Each line is going to be put into the variable `line` so that we can run some command(s) on it. When we're done with our command(s) on that line, the next line will be read, until we run out of lines in our file.
- `find path -name "$line"` The `find` command does a recursive search down from the given path (Pictures in our case). Here we use the `-name` option to find files matching the names in the list.
- `-ls` The `find` command has an option to list out the found files. This is useful for checking on what's been found before taking any action
- `-exec command {} \;` The `-exec` option to find runs the given command on the files that have been found (represented by `{}`)
- `cp -vt` The `-v` option makes `cp` tell us what it's doing. The `-t` option specifies the destination (we give the destination directory immediately after it); otherwise the destination will be assumed to be the last argument.